# Proper way to save tree uri in SAF in android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating an android application using xamarin.android with targetsdk is Marshmallow.

I am using SAF for writing to external sd card (removable media), for this I call an Intent with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree);
StartActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
```

I had saved that tree uri on SharedPreference for long term permission until my device gets rebooted like

```
treeUri.ToString()
```

and read that uri like

```
var str = Android.Net.Uri.Decode(UriString);
var TreeUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(str);
```

And parse this TreeUri to DocumentFile class to manage documents but sometimes in between it missed some part of uri and I need to invoke it again to user to grant permission for managing documents and save the treeuri again.

As we can see this on ES File Explorer that it also ask the user to grant the permission and it maintains the treeuri until the device reboots.

Here is the image of ES File Explorer

[image]

Do correct me what to do to maintain tree uri until device reboots.

Edit:
Here is the TakePersistableUriPermission code:

```
var takeFlags = ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission; 

GrantUriPermission(PackageName, data.Data, takeFlags); 

ContentResolver.TakePersistableUriPermission(data.Data, takeFlags);
```

Comment: In the onActivityResult you should take the persistable uri permissions.

Comment: Already did that.

Comment: var takeFlags = ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission;
               
                        GrantUriPermission(PackageName, data.Data, ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
                        ContentResolver.TakePersistableUriPermission(data.Data, takeFlags);

Comment: When my app starts next time, I fetch treeuri from SharedPreference as stated above. Is it ok the way I did or anything else is required for modification

Comment: You are saving it in shared preference right?

Comment: Yeah! That's right

Comment: Please put code in your post in a code block. Do you like to read code from comments?

Comment: If your permission is valid you can get it from getPersistableUriPermissions(). So you do not need shared preferences.